# Using Visual Studio Intellisense for building jQuery selector strings

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

This is a minor issue, but one I find myself running into:

When I am using jQuery in Visual Studio 2010, I find myself frequently typing:

```
$(#S
```

using Intellisense to find the SomeID object ID:

```
$(#SomeID).click( function() { etc.. })
```

then going back and adding quotes:

```
$('#SomeID').click( function() { etc.. })
```

I find it annoying that if I add the quote first, Visual Studio goes into string mode and I lose Intellisense for finding the object's ID or class.

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Intellisense for jquery on VS2010 is far from perfect,
It has various problems like the one you mentioned above and it is knowN to cause performance issues within VS itself, for me typing at times was unbearably slow.
You could always create some snippets to speed up your worklow, but unfortunately that wont actually fix your problem with the intellisense. Lets hope they release a fix for this in their first service pack.

Comment: This is a little off-topic, but I'm using Eclipse for javascript/jQuery code now, I didn't realize VS had intellisense for jQuery.  Does this work for javascript code that I write as well?  Am I crazy for using eclipse if VS can speed up my production time with intellisense?

Comment: Blowsie, I didn't want to award an answer right away, but I guess the correct answer is "no" at this time.

Comment: DutrowLLC, VS does give you limited intellisense for the javascript that you write. I can't speak as to how good Eclipse is, but I find the VS implementation quite helpful despite some of its shortcomings.